# high priority for I/O operations

Tags: linux, macos, bash, io

I came across this:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice

however, it seems that it is not working on os x, as i got message that command not found.

is there any alternative to it or way to install ionice or way to prioritize O/I operations for a process?

thank you.

feel free to ask aditional question.

Comment: Are you trying this on osx thinking all linux / commandline things )  work on osx?  Sorry dude not always the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, **no**, there is nothing exactly like that in *Os X*.

*Ionice* is a strictly-Linux command, it does not exist in *Unix*, which makes it unlikely it exists in *Os X* either. To make sure, [the list of commands unique to OS X](http://www.matisse.net/OSX/darwin_commands.html) does **not** mention *ionice*.

Also, the FreeBSD online manual does not mention any special capability for either [nice](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/nice/),  [renice](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/8/renice/), [setpriority](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/2/setpriority/) or [getpriority](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/2/getpriority/), beyond the ability to set/modify/display the *overall* scheduling priority of a process or process group. You may query the very same page for `ionice` on a variety of Linux and Unix dialects, including `OS X`: I simply checked them all to see that you are always kicked back to Linux, and one of its dialects.

In other words, I could not find any specific reference to [ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice)'s

> ionice - get/set program **io** scheduling class and priority

(emphasis mine).

Comment: thank you, so this means there is no alternative either, is it?

Comment: @user_pruser Afraid so.